# Fixed width for google visualization tables not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, google-visualization

I am trying to have a google table with fixed widths, but its working out sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

We i have more 2-3 column_headers it works out to have fixed width columns, but when i increase number of columns it doesn't work
Please let me know if i am missing anything, or if there is any better way to do it.

Since there is now alternative to have 2 row headers in google table, i tried to create a dummy table(the one on top)

Ideally want column_header1 on top-table to align with "Col1 Col2 Col3" in bottom table.

Noticed that table is trying to fit to the chrome-page size, can you let me know how to have it as scroll-able table, with required column widths

Also please let me know if there is a way to hide empty row in top-table and how i can add a column to delete row dynamically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: White;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  }

  /* Style the tables */
  .headerformat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: black;
    color: White;
    padding: 25px 25px;
  }

  .oddrowformat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: Lightgray;
    color: Black;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }

  .evenrowformat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: While;
    color: Black;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }

  .selectrowformat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: Lightyellow;
    color: Black;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['table']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable1);

    function drawTable1() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var cssClassNames = {
        headerRow: 'headerformat',
        tableRow: 'evenrowformat',
        oddTableRow: 'oddrowformat',
        selectedTableRow: 'selectrowformat',
      }
      data.addColumn('string', 'ColA');
      data.addColumn('string', 'ColB');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header1');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header2');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header3');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header4');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header5');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header6');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column_header7');
      data.addRows([
        [, , , , , , , , , ]
      ]);
      data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 1, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 2, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 3, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 4, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 5, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 6, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 7, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 8, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableid1'));
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      table.draw(view, {
        allowHtml: true,
        frozenColumns: 1,
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        alternatingRowStyle: true
      });
    }

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(table2);

    function table2() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var cssClassNames = {
        headerRow: 'headerformat',
        tableRow: 'evenrowformat',
        oddTableRow: 'oddrowformat',
        selectedTableRow: 'selectrowformat',
      }
      data.addColumn('string', 'ColA');
      data.addColumn('string', 'ColB');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Col3');
      data.addRows([
        ['Row_data1', 'row2', 0, 0, 12, 11, 222, 3333, 1111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      ]);
      data.setProperty(0, 2, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 3, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 4, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 5, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 6, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 7, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 8, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 9, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 10, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 11, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 12, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 13, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 14, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 15, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 16, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 17, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 18, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 19, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 20, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 21, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 22, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width: 480px;');
      data.setProperty(0, 1, 'style', 'width: 160px;');
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tableid2'));
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      table.draw(view, {
        allowHtml: true,
        frozenColumns: 1,
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        alternatingRowStyle: true
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3><br>Header<br><br></h3>
    <div id="tableid1" />
  </div><br>
  <div id="tableid2" />
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Current output:
[image]

Indented output, with more columns
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.